# Pandas group by variable length of columns if column name is in a list

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

A user can choose if they want to include a column or not to be used later on in a group by statement. If they choose to include the column the colum name gets added to a list, so the list could range from anywhere from 1-6 values. There are three additional columns that will always be used in the group by statement, but the user selected columns will be of variable length

so far I have tried below which have all resulted in an error

```
categorical_fields = []
card_name_match=input("Do you want to include card name first name matches passenger first name: y/n")
if card_name_match=="y":
    categorical_fields.append("name_match")
fare_class_1_cat=input("Do you want to include Fare Class 1 Category: y/n")
if fare_class_1_cat=="y":
    categorical_fields.append("FARECLASS1_cat")
fare_class_2_cat=input("Do you want to include Fare Class 2 Category: y/n")
if fare_class_2_cat=="y":
    categorical_fields.append("FARECLASS2_cat")
distance_cat=input("Do you want to include Distance: y/n")
if distance_cat=="y":
    categorical_fields.append("distance_category")
int_or_domestic=input("Do you want to include if flight was international or domestic: y/n")
if int_or_domestic=="y":
    categorical_fields.append("international_or_domestic")
journey_type=input("Do you want to include journey type of one way, round trip, or different 2nd arrival destination: y/n")
if journey_type=="y":
    categorical_fields.append("dep_to_arr")
```

```
airline_score = airline.groupby([categorical_fields,'category','score','mop']).agg(count=('fs_sham','count'),dollars=('fs_dollars','sum')).reset_index()
ValueError: Grouper and axis must be same length
```

```
categorical_fields.extend(['category','score','mop'])
group_columns = airline.groupby(categorical_fields)
airline_score = airline.groupby(group_columns).agg(count=('fs_sham','count'),dollars=('fs_dollars','sum')).reset_index()
ValueError: Grouper for '<class 'pandas.core.groupby.generic.DataFrameGroupBy'>' not 1-dimensional
```

```
categorical_fields.extend(['category','score','mop'])
airline_score = airline.groupby(airline.columns.isin([categorical_fields])).agg(count=('fs_sham','count'),dollars=('fs_dollars','sum')).reset_index()
ValueError: Grouper and axis must be same length
```

Comment: What is the logic behind this successive grouping: `group_columns = airline.groupby(categorical_fields); airline_score = airline.groupby(group_columns).agg(...`?

Comment: @Timus it was me playing around and trying to get something that worked as everything I was attempting to was giving an error

Comment: Hello, I've validated my answer on personal input data. Please try it and share feeback. Add **your own minimal input data** for [mre] if need be, so answer may be further adapted to your case.

Answer (score 0):

Look at your *airline_score* grouper:

```
[categorical_fields,'category','score','mop']
```

What shape is it? Something like that:

```
[ ['categorical_field1', 'categorical_field2'], 'category','score','mop']
```

That is no 1D list. Instead, build an actual 1D grouper:

```py
grouper = []
grouper.extend(categorical_fields)
grouper.extend(['category','score','mop'])

# *Now* grouper is truly 1D

airline.groupby(by = grouper).agg( # remainder of your line
```

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, the main problem is that you're using the columns (*chosen by the user*) — which happen to have a length less than the DataFrame `airline` columns, even after being extended — as the grouper of [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html). That's why this [`ValueError`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/main/pandas/core/groupby/grouper.py#L1063) is trigged.

I'll give a suggestion of a possible fix and also an attempt to make your code a bit clearer :

```
d = {
    "name_match": "Do you want to include card name first name matches passenger first name? (y/n): ",
    "FARECLASS1_cat": "Do you want to include Fare Class 1 Category? (y/n): ",
    "FARECLASS2_cat": "Do you want to include Fare Class 2 Category? (y/n): ",
    "distance_category": "Do you want to include Distance? (y/n): ",
    "international_or_domestic": "Do you want to include if flight was international or domestic? (y/n): ",
    "dep_to_arr": "Do you want to include journey type of one way, round trip, or different 2nd arrival destination? (y/n): "
}

categorical_fields = [c for c, p in d.items() if input(p).lower() == "y"]

grouper = (
    df.columns.intersection(categorical_fields)
        .union(["category", "score", "mop", "fs_dollars", "fs_sham"])
)

airline_score = (
    airline.groupby(list(grouper), as_index=False)
        .agg(count=("fs_sham","count"), dollars=("fs_dollars", "sum"))
)
```